# how to check null or not if mysql datatype is timestamp with a default value of "0000-00-00 00:00"?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to figure out the best way to return `true` or `false` if a mysql datatype is `TIMESTAMP` which is null returns date `0000-00-00 00:00`

I tried it something like this -

```
if($mycolumn == "0000-00-00 00:00") {
    echo "null";
} else {
    echo "not null";
}
```

This is the `mysql` for timestamp column -

```
last_login TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Can I get to know if this is not the way to the job, then how do I best check for that as a null time or not..?

Thank you.

Comment: If your db having default value then this the way...

Comment: Kindly brief the scenario why u need this. Its will better for understanding. Since when no value for last_login the default value is filled by db. So if you want to check whether this fellow is logging first time or not this is the way.

Comment: 1. 0000-00-00 00:00 is not null value. 2. What is wrong with your decision?

Comment: yes just I want to check whether a particular user is login first or not

Comment: Ur Code is ok. What issue u r facing now?

Comment: @user3733831 the solution I provided doesn't suit your purpose?

Comment: @яша yes I think its the way that I need to go...

Comment: @user3733831 instead of reassigning your value in php it wil be immidiately out for you from the table something like :

select user, id, telephone, IF(last_login = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', "null", "not null") as last_login from Table .... Hence when you fetch your columns and the ("null","not null") will be ready for you

Comment: Why is the default set to that time? why not `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` since when they register they are logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you is to use this [method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT  IF(last_login = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', "null", "not null") as last_login from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Username and password arbitrary but if you group a count you can check if the last_login is greater than 0.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT username, COUNT(last_login) AS date_checker FROM sessions
        WHERE password = '123456'
) AS tmp WHERE (date_checker = 0 OR username = 'foobar')
```